# Как сбросить поле ввода с его стилями?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть у меня `input`, которое лежит в `div`'e. На `div`'e висит `CSS` ошибки/ корректного ввода в `input`. Как сделать так, чтобы нажав на `checkbox`, я сбрасывал поле `input`и приводил `div`к первоначальным настройкам (то есть к тем, которые были активны до взаимодействия с полем ввода)? То есть проблема в том, что когда я нажимаю в поле ввода, `border` `div`'a красится в зависимости от корректности ввода данных. Но сбрось я `input` (`.value=""`), цвет на `div` рамке остается, т.к. классы актуальны. Обратись к родителю `input`'a (после взаимодействия с `checkbox`'ом), и в классы заново пропиши первоначальные стили, то, к примеру, `flexbox` смещается.

```
<div class="field">
  <input type="text">
</div>
<input type="checkbox">
```

Comment: Сам ты ксс. ЦСС!

Comment: описание п...ц товарищи...

Comment: Добавьте пример того, что вы хотите получить, судя по комментариям.. большая часть людей не поймёт чего вы хотите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Держите. Запоминает название класов при нажатии инпута и дива. Если убираешь - восстанавливает названием классов.

```js
var className; // будем хранить изнчальное имя класса стилей css input
var divClassname // будем хранить изнчальное имя класса стилей css div
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click',function(e){
var $checkbox = $(e.target)
if ($checkbox.prop('checked')){ // если галка отмечена .
var $div = $($checkbox.prev('div')[0]) // находим элемент div
var $input = $($checkbox.prev('div').find('input[type=text]')[0]); // находим ближайший input который лежит не на одном уровне в блоке div.
className = $input.attr('class') // запоминаем название класса которое было изначально.
divClassname = $div.attr('class') // запоминаем название класса которое было изначально.
$input.removeAttr('class'); // удаляем название класса инпута.
$div.removeAttr('class'); // удаляем название класса дива.
console.log($input[0]);
console.log($div[0]);
} else { // если галка не стоит на чекбоксе.
 var $input = $($checkbox.prev('div').find('input[type=text]')[0]),
 $div = $($checkbox.prev('div')[0]);
 $input.addClass(className) // Возобнавляем значение импута если чекбокс не нажат.
 $div.addClass(divClassname) // Возобнавляем значение дива если чекбокс не нажат.
 console.log($input[0])
 console.log($div[0])
}
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "field">
  <input type = "text" class="error"> <!-- изначально класс error -->
</div>
<input type = "checkbox">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    // Удалить или добавить в зависимости от того находится или нет
    $('.field > input').toggleClass('err init')
  })
});
```

```css
input{
 margin: 1px;
}
.err {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.init {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field">
  <input type="text" class="inpt init">
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="inpt init">
</div>
<input type="checkbox">
```